# The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime, data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Tags: sql, sql-server

Runtime exception:

> The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type
>   resulted in an out-of-range value.

Code:

```
INSERT INTO [Migrated].[dbo].[MyTables] (LegacyId,DeedDate)
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        a.[IPLID], CONVERT(nvarchar(255), a.[Deeddate], 127) 
    FROM 
        [Legacy].[dbo].[MyTables2] as a
```

- MyTables --> DeedDate  datetime  Allow Null
- MyTables2 --> Deeddate  nvarchar(255)  Allow Null

Hope I have done it correctly. But why it gives above error ?

I'm using SQL Server 2014 express.

**Note :** Can you tell me how to find out defects on `MyTables2` `Deeddate` ? I mean different date formats and etc.Or Replace such dates with `NULL`.

Comment: you are trying to insert `nvarchar` into a `datetime` column. the error message is clear.

Comment: You have a date before 1.1.1753 (or after 31.12.9999)?

Comment: @vkp That's why I have converted it.Am I wrong ?

Comment: Try using smaller and smaller sets of MyTables2 to determine exactly which value(s) are causing the issue.

Comment: you are still converting it to nvarchar.

Comment: How can I do @Steven ? It's having `113,237` records.

Comment: @JamesZ Do you know how to query that ?

Comment: OK,then can you show me how to do it correctly @vkp ?

Comment: you already have the answer below.

Comment: @vkp same error no ? :(

Comment: show some sample data from the table.

Comment: I would alter your SELECT statement and just run that until you find the error.  Do TOP 50000 and see if you get the same error.  If you do, try 25000.  Then continue until you find at least the first record in error.

Comment: @vkp Can you give me a specific query to retrieve defects ? Otherwise it's having `113,237` records.

Comment: is the format of `Deeddate` in `MyTables2` like '2000-01-01' ? can you show that?

Comment: @vkp can you tell me how to get that value ? At this moment dates on that column is like this `1/19/2000`,`2/13/1995`.But it may have defects. Please tell me how to query that ?

Comment: try `select max(right(Deeddate)) from MyTables2` and check the value you get. This would tell you if the year part is not between 1753 and 9999

Comment: @vkp Above one is not working.Can you tell me how to Replace such defects with `NULL` ?

Comment: can you tell me what the result of my previous comment was? that is just to check values.

Comment: @vkp It asks more parameters for the `right`.What should I give ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found out the defect dates by using [**ISDATE function**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187347.aspx) and removed it.After that it works.Cheers :)

This works then :

```
INSERT INTO [Migrated].[dbo].[MyTables] (LegacyId,DeedDate)
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        a.[IPLID], CONVERT(nvarchar(255), a.[Deeddate], 127) 
    FROM 
        [Legacy].[dbo].[MyTables2] as a
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2012+, you can use `TRY_CONVERT()` which will return `NULL` rather than an error:

```
INSERT INTO [Migrated].[dbo].[MyTables](LegacyId, DeedDate)
    SELECT DISTINCT a.[IPLID], TRY_CONVERT(nvarchar(255), a.[Deeddate], 127)
    FROM [Legacy].[dbo].[MyTables2] a;
```

You can also use this to determine where the format is not correct:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM (SELECT a.[IPLID], a.[Deeddate],
             TRY_CONVERT(nvarchar(255), a.[Deeddate], 127) as datestr
      FROM [Legacy].[dbo].[MyTables2] a
     ) a
WHERE datestr IS NULL;
```

Comment: first query says like this `'nvarchar' is not a recognized built-in function name.` Why ?

Comment: I'm using `SQL server 2014 express`.

Comment: It is entirely unclear why that error would be returned.  In the context in this query, `nvarchar(255)` is clearly a data type declaration.